# React Native FlatList preformance issue with 400+ .json

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have some preformance issues with FlatList. The idea is to display the list of the songs, as flat list. List has 2 columns, with bookmark icon and title.

On list item click I'm navigating to a different route passing song text from JSON as a param. On this route I'm just displaying song text

Json file structure:

`[{"number":"1","title":"some title","text":"some text"},{...},{...}]`

App overview:

I'm importing JSON file:
`import Songs from '../db/songs.json';` (Songs arr has 400+ objects inside)

---

`renderItem()` function:

```
renderItem = (title, text) => {
    let newTitle = title;
    if (title.length > 38) {
      newTitle = title.substr(0, 38) + '...';
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.listMainContainer}>
        <View style={styles.listIconContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Icon name="bookmark" size={20} style={{opacity: 0.2}} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 0.9}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() =>
              this.props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: 'Song',
                params: {songText: text, songTitle: title},
              })
            }>
            <Text style={styles.listText}>{newTitle}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

---

`render()` function

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <FlatList
          data={Songs}
          renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item.title, item.text)}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.number}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

---

The preformance is very poor. It's not about how fast is list loaded. When I press an item, there is a serious lag between press and `<TouchableOpacity>` action.

I've tried to use a different approach, for example, I wanted to render the list using `map()` function

```
     renderList = () => {
       return (
        Songs.map(item => {
          if (item.title.length > 38) {
            item.title = item.title.substr(0, 38) + '...';
          }
          return (
            <View key={item.number} style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <View style={{ flex: 0.1, marginTop: 8, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Icon name="bookmark" size={20} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={{ flex: 0.9 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginTop: 8 }}>{item.title}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          )
        })
    )
  };
```

The  preformance lag has gone but it took few seconds to load the list (on emulator)

Any tips?

Comment: Can you employ paging on your songs returned to JSON? That would help greatly and you can use FlatList's `onEndReachedThreshold` to append gradually.

Comment: Hmm, I can try that

Comment: I don't think with 400+ data in flatlist can create issue. Please check it with release build also, debug build is slow in react-native.

Answer (score 0):

When you have huge amount of data, it is always suggested to use a recyclerview, because it overcomes most of the limitations of the FlatList, VirtualizedList and ListView.

Follow the link 
[react-native-recyclerview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recyclerview-list) for the documentation.